# Implement retry mechanism on main thread

Tags: c#

How would you implement an unlimited retry mechanism in case internal logics fails

something like this, but here you have only one change

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
 {
      ILog Log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Program));
      try
      {
          StartWorking(Log);
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
          Log.Error("Main exited with error: {0}. Restarting app", ex);
          Thread.Sleep(5000);

          StartWorking(Log);
      }
  }

  private static void StartWorking(ILog Log)
  {
      Foo t = new Foo();
      t.ReadConfiguration();
      t.Login();
      t.StartWorking();
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use a `while` loop:

```
while (true)
{
    try
    {
        StartWorking(Log);
        // No exception was thrown, exit the loop
        break;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.Error("Main exited with error: {0}. Restarting app", ex);
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
    }
}
```

Note however that this is very bad practice. You definitely don't want to be doing this. Instead you should have a retry logic that after a number of retries just gives up. For example:

```
const int maxRetries = 5;
for (var i = 0; i < maxRetries; i++)
{
    try
    {
        StartWorking(Log);
        // No exception was thrown, exit the loop
        break;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.Error("Main exited with error: {0}. Restarting app", ex);
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
    }

    if (i == maxRetries - 1)
    {
        throw new Exception("Sorry, we have reached the maximum number of retries for this operation, just giving up");
    }
}
```

Comment: In many real-world scenarios it's also useful to use exponential backoff (increasing sleep time exponentially up to a certain amount) instead of sleeping fixed 5 seconds every time.